# Time out publishing large site into Firebase Hosting and how to deploy zips

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I'm deploying a large static site. It contains around 71000 small files with a total size of near of 2GB. After package and compress, the tar.gz file size is no more than 33MB.

I have a good internet connection (1G download / 100M upload).

Executing `firebase deploy --only hosting` exit with a timeout error after ten minutes.

```
[2022-10-15T17:45:08.396Z] Error: Timed out.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/angelcc/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/utils.js:253:49)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

1. How can I deploy sites of this size in firebase hosting?
2. To avoid timeouts, Is there a way to push a compress file with the full site?

Comment: angelcervera, do let me know if my recommendations were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The time out error could be caused due to large number of files being transferred and the socket getting closed during this process due to different issues, may be a slow connection,or a slower transfer rate over the site.You may try and delete the hidden folder in your project root directory named similar as  `.firebase/hosting.*.cache` and try deploying again.

If you are deploying from a GitHub action or a Cloud Build step a stable and good connection should be able to successfully deploy these .If you are using a local machine, there's an environment variable that can be set to change the concurrency of the Hosting upload process. `FIREBASE_HOSTING_UPLOAD_CONCURRENCY`, which can be set to any number (e.g. 100) and it will chunk the files into groups of that size to send to the version (populateFiles in the logs).
Also it is recommended [limiting the number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-hosting-resources#release-storage-settings) of releases,for large sites you can keep the number of releases less than 10 - maybe even 5 - so that (a) it saves on the very minimal storage costs and (b) speeds up the process when pushing files up for a new version.

I recommend you to check the links here for detailed information on [Static Website hosting](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website) and [Storage tips](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)